# Laravel Unit Tests cannot find namespaced class

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4

I have a pretty basic Laravel setup that I am starting to test. I have my own library files in the folder app/framework and all the files are under the namespace "CompanyName\Framework". I added these files to the composer.json file to have it autoloaded in my app.

My composer.json is then :

```
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/framework"
    ]
```

In my controller I can use my library fine and autoloading seems to work. When I try to test that controller in my unit test it says

....PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CompanyName\Framework\DatabaseUpdater' not found in C:\
Production\CompanyName\laravel\app\controllers\DatabaseController.php on line 19

Why is that namespace suddently invalid when I call my controller from my unit test ? The unit test itself is very basic, it is simply a **$this->client->request('GET', '/')**. Absolutely everything works perfectly *except* the unit test.